# Change View Controller with another view Controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, push

Suppose I have view controllers named A, B, C, D. I am using push to go from A -> B -> C. Now I want to go to D from C and when I press back button from D, it should go to A. How Can I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: use this -> self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

Comment: But It will take me to A.. I want to go directly from C to D.. and It should Pop All the view Controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your back button with a custom one, and add an action which will pop you to the **rootViewController** inside that `UINavigationController` you are currently. (**popToRootViewController** means removing all other controllers from the navigation stack and go the first one)

On your last viewController put these lines:

### Objective-C

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Go to root" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popToRootNavigationViewController:)];
}

- (void)popToRootNavigationViewController:(UIBarButtonItem *)button {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

### Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Go to root", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "popToRootNavigationViewController:")
}

func popToRootNavigationViewController(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: In function `self.navigationController?. popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` should be used in place of `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: @RiddhiShah yeah a typo there, thank you for pointing out! Updated :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pop to root (A), for example D --> A (directly)

```
 self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

If you want to go back to the previous view controller , for ex : D -- > C or c--> B or B to A

```
 self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `UINavigationController` you can call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated(_:)`, it will take you back to the first controller of your pile.

So use a NavController, set A as root, and in D, `popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated: